# can we set log4j Appenders in subfiolders

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a requirement where I need to zip log files everyday, but this is not for application log files. In my application there are various feeder directories where input files are placed and processed and at same place this logs are generated for individual input files. there are many feeder directories I want to use Log4j utilities to create zip for this log files on everyday basis.
The bad way will be to write appenders for all this directory locations, can anyone suggest if there is any generic approach ?